# Typoscript: Missing escape character?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

My Typoscript is:

```
page.headerData.10 = TEXT
page.headerData.10.value (
    document.write('<scr' + 'ipt src="' + src + '"></scr' + 'ipt>');
)
```

The HTML output is:

```
document.write('<scr' iptsrc="" src=""></scr' + 'ipt>');
```

Why is it different? Am I missing an escape character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, but it seems to be a bug.

In fact, it works without the spaces before and after the "+".

```
page.headerData.10 = TEXT
page.headerData.10.value (
    document.write('<scr'+'ipt src="'+src+'"></scr'+'ipt>');
)
```